# Error code 453 while trying to create a Twitter bot with NodeJS and twitter-api-v2

Tags: node.js, twitter, twitter-api-v2

I am trying to create a very simple bot using `twitter-api-v2`, `NodeJS` and Twitter's **free tier** for developers. I have tried following a tutorial by [Dom the dev](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fD-GRCH_tks&pp=ygUSdHdpdHRlciBib3Qgbm9kZWpz) but I keep running into the same bug, no matter what I try.

**The error message**

> You currently have access to a subset of Twitter API v2 endpoints and
> limited v1.1 endpoints (e.g. media post, oauth) only. If you need
> access to this endpoint, you may need a different access level. You
> can learn more here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/portal/product

**What I have tried so far**

- Making sure my settings are correct on https://developer.twitter.com using two different accounts, including one that should be working because it has worked in the past (more precisely in October) It was used by somebody else than myself.
- Making sure my code doesn't contain any typo.
- Searching on the Web. Incidentally, the issue I'm talking about seems common, [but the solution is not so clear](https://devcommunity.x.com/t/453-you-currently-have-access-to-a-subset-of-twitter-api-v2-endpoints-and-limited-v1-1-endpoints/199424).

### My project has three files

**twitterClient.js**

```
const { TwitterApi } = require("twitter-api-v2");

const client = new TwitterApi({
    appKey: "",
    appSecret: "",
    accessToken: "",
    accessSecret: ""
});

const rwClient = client.readWrite;

module.exports = rwClient;
```

**index.js**

```
const rwClient = require("./twitterClient.js");

const tweet = async () => {
    try {
        await rwClient.v1.tweet("Good morning!");
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
}

tweet();
```

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
  "twitter-api-v2": "^1.15.2"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer to my own question:

This line:

> await rwClient.v1.tweet("Good morning!");

Has to be changed for this:

> await rwClient.v2.tweet("Good morning!");

And voilà!